# How can I make a class "public except for" this assembly?

Tags: c#

I have `class Foo` in a library project that I would like to prevent using in my application project. I am reworking my application to not use `class Foo` but I have to do this incrementally. `Class Foo` is used in the library so excluding the file is not an acceptable answer. So how can I make my application blind to `class Foo`? Also note I cannot make it `internal` because other libraries need `class Foo`.

Comment: How many entry points does this Library have? You could add your own wrapper project which acts as a decorator and intercepts any calls to public Foo and returns an Exception for example.

Comment: [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) may help

Comment: There's not a mechanism to allow a class to be used in all libraries _except_ a specific one.  You can use `InternalsVisibleTo` to make an internal class visible to _specific_ libraries, but that sounds like it;s not what you want.  I think static code analysis (or a search) is your best bet.  There's no way to "prevent" it.

Comment: I think the [Obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/22kk2b44%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) attribute is exactly for that.

Comment: @KingCronus Several its a rather larger library. What I really need is "public except for". But didn't think of that phrase until 15 minutes ago.

Comment: InternalsVisibleTo is good but I would need to add over a dozen libraries to that list.

Answer (score 4):

`protected internal` is what you are looking for.

**Accessibility of access modifiers in C#:**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't allow `class Foo` to be used by other libraries. If this class was only used in its own assembly then it work.

Comment: Also protected internal doesn't work namespace members such as class, and interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of your library and in that, change `Foo` class modifier to internal. after building it replace the old reference with this new one and keep other projects references to old library intact.

I only recommend this solution for temporary maintenance.